If the matroids associated to two finite subsets of the same vector space are isomorphic, are these two finite subsets linearly equivalent?
Let $E$ be a finite subset of ${\mathbb{F}_2}^n$, the $n$-dimensional vector space over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$ of $2$ elements. Let $M_E$ denote the associated matroid on $E$ where the independent sets of $M_E$ are the linearly independent subsets of $E$.
Suppose that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are finite subsets of ${\mathbb{F}_2}^n$ that are linearly equivalent, i.e. there is an invertible linear operator $h$ on ${\mathbb{F}_2}^n$ such that $h(E_1) = E_2$. Then $M_{E_1}$ and $M_{E_2}$ are isomorphic, since $A \subseteq E_1$ is linearly independent if and only if $h(A) \subseteq E_2$ is linearly independent.
Is the converse true? Namely, if two finite subsets $E_1, E_2 \subseteq {\mathbb{F}_2}^n$ define isomorphic matriods $M_{E_1} \cong M_{E_2}$, are $E_1$ and $E_2$ necessarily linearly equivalent?
P.S. The question I am asking here is related to two questions that I have asked on MSE: Q1 and Q2.

This is a well-known result, usually stated as "binary matroids are projectively unique." A Google search on this phrase will produce many references.

Thank you, Professor Stanley.

Yes, the converse is true. In $\mathbb{F}_2^n$, a linear matroid $M_E$ uniquely determines $E$ up to isomorphism.
Proof: Pick a basis $v_1, \dots, v_d$ of $M_E$. For any other vector $v=c_1v_1+\dots+c_dv_c$ in $E$ we have that $\{v_1, \dots, v_d\}+v-v_i$ is independent in $M_E$ iff $c_i\neq 0$ for any $1\leq i \leq d$. Since the coefficients are in $\mathbb{F}_2$, this is enough information to uniquely determine the coefficients and thus the vector space up to isomorphism.
